# How do apps tell if there is a problem with ssl?

Tags: email, sslstrip

Email clients and other software use ssl. But what if someone is doing a mitm with sslstrip? how can i tell?

Comment: The TLS library the app uses obviously can detect this. The question is, does the app react accordingly or just silently ignores the error ? I've seen the latter with a mobile banking app; pretty scary.

Comment: Tools like sslstrip remove the usage of TLS. Thus the TLS library will not be used at all and can thus not detect the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`sslstrip` works by changing all `https` links to `http`. It is restricted to HTTP but tools for other protocols might exist or at least are easily doable. These kind of tools don't break the TLS connection but instead enforce a downgrade to an insecure unencrypted connection.

How good these kind of tools can work depends a lot on the application and on the protocols used. With IMAP, POP3, SMTP, FTP and probably others there are two ways to use TLS:

- Implicit TLS: In this mode the client connects via TCP and then immediately upgrades the connection to TLS. This is done on different ports (i.e. 993 instead of 143 for IMAP) and on these ports only TLS is expected. Thus there is no way for a man in the middle to strip the usage of TLS, all it can do is to deny usage of these ports which might cause some applications to downgrade to explicit TLS.
- Explicit TLS: In this mode the client connects via TCP and after some plain text communication it upgrades the existing connection to TLS by issuing a `STARTTLS` or similar command (`STLS` with POP3, `AUTH TLS` with FTP). If there is a man in the middle (s)he might modify the communication so that the client assumes, that TLS is not possible. The behavior then depends on the client and sometimes on its configuration: some clients will silently use the plain text connection while others will throw an error because they expected to use an encrypted connection.

And even if this is outside of your original question: if a downgrade to plain unencrypted communication is not possible the attacker might try to use tools like [sslsplit](https://www.roe.ch/SSLsplit) to do a man-in-the-middle attack against TLS itself. There are still lots of applications vulnerable against these kind of attack (see [VU#582497](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/582497)) because they fail to validate TLS certificates at all or omit critical parts of the validation like checking the host name. Thus in lots of cases a TLS man-in-the-middle attack is possible without the user detecting it.